# VBA Function Returning Type Mismatch

Tags: regex, excel, vba, function

I have a function calling another function. This was all one function but it got too big.

```vb
Function Wave(SubjectLine As Range)
Dim SubV
SubV = SubjectLine.Value
   Dim regEx, Match, Matches   ' Create variable.
   Set regEx = New RegExp   ' Create a regular expression.
   regEx.Pattern = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][a-z][a-z][a-z]?[a-z]?[a-z]?[a-z]"
   regEx.IgnoreCase = True   ' Set case insensitivity.
   regEx.Global = True   ' Set global applicability.
   Set Matches = regEx.Execute(SubV)   ' Execute search.
   For Each Match In Matches   ' Iterate Matches collection.
      RetStr = RetStr & Match.Value

   Next
    If RetStr = 0 Then
        WaveSort = "Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If


    DivR = DivResult(Left(RetStr, 5))

...then something else
```

```vb
Function DivResult(PL As Integer)


        Select Case PL
        Case 1
        DivResult = "Wave1"
        ...
        Case Else
        DivResult = "NO"
        End Select
End Function
```

My result is alway Data Type Mismatch. I have tried changing variable types and renaming and everything I can think of. Left turns the variable to an integer so i just embraced it but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Sidenote, you can replace your whole regex string with `[0-9]{5}-[a-z]{3,6}` (much more legible)

Comment: Example of the data the regex is run on?  In order of appearance.  1.`RetStr` is a string so it should be `If LEN(RetStr) = 0`. 2 `Function DivResult(PL as Integer)` expects an integer but you are passing an implied `string` - `RetStr`. If this should be an integer, you should be converting before passing. 3. Each function should have a defined return type. If DivResult should always return a String, you should have `Function DivResult(PL as Integer) as String`  4. DivResult is comparing integers `1`  as an integer to  String values. Note, not right now because you changed PL to integer.